# IoC-контейнер spring и обращение через интерфейсы

Tags: java, spring

Присутствует класс IndexMatrix и он имплемитирует интерфейс IMatrix:

```
public class IndexMatrix implements IMatrix{

    private int[][] matrix;

    @Override
    public int[][] getMatrix() {
        return matrix;
    }

    @Override
    public void generateMatrix(int sizeX, int sizeY) {
        int mass[][] = new int[sizeX][sizeY];

        for (int i = 1; i <= sizeX; i++){
            for (int j = 1; j <= sizeY; j++){
                mass[i-1][j-1] = (10 * i) + j;
            }
        }
        matrix = mass;
    }
}
```

Класс Main вызывает класс Menu:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        menu.start();
    }
}
```

Как мне в классе Menu нужно реализовать взаимосвязи, что в case 1 дёргался объект IMatrix и после выполнения switch работали методы?

Т.е. как сделать, чтобы находились нужные @Bean и где вообще нужно пометить @Bean? где описть Contex?

```
switch(number) {
case 1:
                        getQuestion();
                        matrix = IndexMatrix();
                        break;
....
}
....
matrix.generateMatrix(sizeX, sizeY);
printer.print(matrix);
....
```

---

```
@Configurable
@ComponentScan
public class Configuration {
    @Bean(name = "IndexMatrix")
    public IMatrix IndexMatrix() {
        return new IndexMatrix();
    }
    @Bean(name = "Printer")
    public IPrinter Printer() {
        return new Printer();
    }
}

matrix = (IMatrix) context.getBean("IndexMatrix"); //примерно так, но нельзя
                                            //как-то сократить запись?
```

p.s. формулировка вопроса, как понимаю.

Comment: Какой Contex вы хотите описать?

Comment: Вы хотите "внедрить" ссылку на объект `IndexMatrix` в класс `Menu`?

Comment: @notaProgrammer да хочу, проверьте, так ли это делается, но мне кажется, что я ошибся и можно более изящно сделать. Я добавил код, который написал.

Comment: @RomanC я обновил код, посмотрите

Comment: @KeyJibo Много ошибок

Comment: @RomanC так может поможете?

Comment: @KeyJibo Не вижу смысла, а чем вам не нравится ответ?

Comment: @RomanC не используя xml, только аннотации требуется

Comment: @KeyJibo Я не видел, где вы используете xml?

Comment: @RomanC без xml нужно, поэтому я и не использую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аннотация **`@Autowired`** делает в точности то, что Вам нужно. Для этого нужно настроить IoC Container, чтобы он искал компоненты в Вашем пакете:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan ("your.package")
public class YourConfiguration {
    ...
}

@Component // По умолчанию имя будет "matrix1"
public class Matrix1 implements IMatrix {
    ...
}

@Component
public class Matrix2 implements IMatrix {
    ...
}

@Component
public class Matrix3 implements IMatrix {
    ...
}

public class Menu {
    @Autowired private IMatrix matrix1; // Здесь внедрение будет происходить не по типу, а по имени
    @Autowired private IMatrix matrix2;
    @Autowired private IMatrix matrix3;

    public void doSomething() {
       switch(number) {
          case 1:
             matrix1.someMethod();
             break;
          case 2:
             matrix2.someMethod();
             break;
          case 3:
             matrix3.someMethod();
             break;
       }
    }
}
```

**Как работает аннотация `@Autowired`:** При запуске приложения Spring контейнер будет "сканировать" пакет `your.package` (который настраивается с помощью аннотации `@ComponentScan`) на наличие компонентов (`Component`, `Controller`, `Entity`, ...). Если такие имеются, Spring контейнер создаст объект данного класса, внедрив все зависимости (поля помеченные аннотацией `@Autowired`) и вызвав конструктор по умолчанию.

Разумеется, для того чтобы это все работало необходимо создать объект класса, который реализует один из интерфейсов: `BeanFactory` или `ApplicationContext`. Для этого смотрите:

- [Документацию](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans)
- [Замечательные видео-уроки](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GB8k2-Egfv0&list=PLC97BDEFDCDD169D7) (на англ.)

**Недостаток использования аннотации `@Autowired`:** Для того, чтобы указать Spring контейнеру управлять объектом класса Вы используете одну из аннотаций (`Component`, `Controller`, `Service`, ...) на класс. К сожалению, если Вам нужно **несколько объектов одного класса** аннотация `@Autowired` Вам не подходит. В данном случае определять компоненты нужно в xml-файле, указывая `Qualifier` для каждого компонента одного и того же класса:

```
<bean id="..." class="...">
   <qualifier value="qualifierName" />
   ...
</bean>
```

Далее внедрить компонент можно следующим образом:

```
@Autowired 
@Qualifier("qualifierName")
private YourClass clazz;
```

Comment: А если таких классов как IndexMatrix - 3? И от значения свича, зависит, какой объект матрицы пристроится? Я в каждом из кейсов вызываю разную матрицу (IMatrix) context.getBean("IndexMatrix")

Comment: matrix = IndexMatrix(); .... matrix = SecondMatrix();- сделать такой вызов в кейсе

Comment: @KeyJibo, я дополнил ответ.

Comment: @KeyJibo, Вы не правильно понимаете суть **Dependency Injection**. Она как раз и заключается в том, что не нужно писать `new SomeClass();` (инстанциировать и инициализировать объект класса `SomeClass`). За Вас это делает Spring контейнер. Есть два вида Dependency Injection: constructor-based и setter-based. **Вы не можете внедрить зависимость в локальную переменную, только в переменную экземпляра класса** (в примере выше `private IMatrix matrix;`).

Comment: у меня есть три разных класса-матриц наследующие IMatrix. Мне поставили задачу, чтобы в каждом из трёх кейсов вызывалась разная матрица, в зависимости от свича. Т.е. мы объявили @Authowired IMatrix matrix вверху, а затем в кейсе просто написал matrix = IndexMatrix() и оно присвоило объект. XML нельзя использовать. Мне кажется, что так всё-таки можно, даже если я не понимаю ещё этого.

Comment: @KeyJibo, я изменил ответ. Посмотрите, правильно ли я Вас понял?

Comment: Да, я это имел ввиду, только нельзя ли сделать(именно в этом я не уверен), чтобы не было matrix1..2..3, а только matrix? Они же по сути все объекты IMatrix?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77805/discussion-between-not-a-programmer-and-keyjibo).